# run code on a edittext depending on what is focused

Tags: android, try-catch, android-edittext

I want to change some property's of a edittext depending on what is focused.
This is what I have so far. Am I doing this right? if so what do I enter in the try-catch statement, I am new to using them

```
    try{
        textbox = (EditText) findViewById(getCurrentFocus().getId());
    }catch(???){
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You do know that try-catch is for 'trying' something which may throw an exception and 'catching' the exception if it happens. Ideally in most instances of well written code, you never want the 'catch' block to execute (or if it does, you use it to 'handle' the exception that has been thrown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better add OnFocusChange Listeners to the other UI elements, and change the proreties from this listeners... [this should work](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)

Comment: if I use this method how do I determine if the focused element is a edittext?

Comment: Implementing this method you'd have deal with onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) from this View you can find out whether it's edtitext or not... that's if i understood you correctly...